# Animate numbers from 0 to Value with Comma - Value is pulled from var

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Struggling with this one so any ideas or suggestions are really appreciated.

I have a calculation (working) that counts how many days have passed since 01/01/2021 and * by a value. I would like to animate from 0 to the value over a period of 3 seconds, however, I don't know how to get around commas - can get it working without.

Any suggestions?

```js
var startDate = new Date('01-01-2021');
var today = new Date();
var diff = Math.floor((today - startDate)/(1000*60*60*24))
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
var answer = diff * 134256;
 
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
      val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
    return val;
}
document.getElementById("CCalc").innerHTML = (commaSeparateNumber(answer));
```

```html
<p id="CCalc" class="fig-number"></p>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `jquery` and `jquery-animate`? There's no jQuery anywhere in the question/code.

Comment: _"...can get it working without."_ - The example in the question doesn't animate anything nor does it work at all. It just ends with `NaN`

Comment: Hi Andreas, it does work and shows the value of 39,471,264. As per my question, I'm looking for some guidance on how to animate it. As all my attempts have failed that is why it is tagged in those sections.

Comment: _"it does work"_ not for me..., _"I'm looking for some guidance on how to animate it"_ -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code with jQuery:

```js
var startDate = new Date('01-01-2021');
var today = new Date();
var diff = Math.floor((today - startDate)/(1000*60*60*24))
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
var answer = diff * 134256;
 
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
      val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
    return val;
}
document.getElementById("CCalc").innerHTML = parseFloat(commaSeparateNumber(answer).replace(/,/g, ''));


$(".fig-number").each(function () {
    $(this)
      .prop("Counter", 0)
      .animate(
        {
          Counter: $(this).text()
        },
        {
          duration: 3000,
          easing: "swing",
          step: function (now, tween) {
            // Check added for decimal number
            if(parseInt(tween.end) == parseFloat(tween.end)){
                var number = Math.ceil(now);
              $(this).text(number.toLocaleString());
            }
          },
        }
      );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="CCalc" class="fig-number">39471264</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. I'm going to look into parseFloat for future applications =)